# Linking Zendesk to Identityserver4

Tags: identityserver4, zendesk

Using IdentityServer4 as a dedicated ASP.NET Core service, which is hosting the ASP.NET Identity MVC scaffolded pages.
We have our application (React front-end), which redirects to the identity server if user is not logged in, using OAUTH processes

Problem case;
We'd like to set up zendesk as our helpcenter, but we'd like this to be behind a logged-in user wall.
Zendesk allows either SAML or JWT Token (this is not even an auth standard, just a token mechanism, but anyhow). SAML is not available on IdentityServer unless going for a rather expensive add-on.

What we'd like to do is go for the route of using the JWT token approach. From what I understood, we fill in a log-in url in zendesk, which links to our identity application.
After logging in (or when the user is already logged in), we need to redirect the user to a specific Zendesk endpoint, with a JWT token appended to the URL.

I understand there's the TokenClient that allows to call the correct endpoints to generate tokens, but isn't that the wrong tool to use here since this would mean the proces would go outbound, and inbound on the connect/token endpoint again?
Is there some class we can use in IdentityServer to create such token?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  It's something I'm also struggling with.

Answer (score 1):

Zendesk has some code examples for this scenario: [examples](https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_jwt_sso_examples). Specifically the [C# handler example](https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_jwt_sso_examples/blob/master/c_sharp_handler.cs).

In your case you could add the sample code to an api controller called LaunchZendeskController.

Prototype example

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class LaunchZendeskController : ControllerBase
    {
        private const string SHARED_KEY = "{my zendesk token}";
        private const string SUBDOMAIN = "{my zendesk subdomain}";

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            TimeSpan t = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
            int timestamp  = (int) t.TotalSeconds;

            var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>() {
                { "iat", timestamp },
                { "jti", System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString() }
                // { "name", currentUser.name },
                // { "email", currentUser.email }
            };
            string token = JWT.JsonWebToken.Encode(payload, SHARED_KEY, JWT.JwtHashAlgorithm.HS256);
            string redirectUrl = "https://" + SUBDOMAIN + ".zendesk.com/access/jwt?jwt=" + token;
            
            return Redirect(redirectUrl);
        }    
    }
```

That way when you browse/redirect to https://YourIdpUrl/launchzendesk a token will be created using the shared key you [generated](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203663816) and you will get redirected to Zendesk with the created token.

Note: the sample is rather old and for dotnet core you should probably use another token generator class. Most likely use nuget package: System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt